# Google BigQuery, I lost null row when using 'unnest' function

Tags: sql, null, google-bigquery, unnest

```
#StandardSQL
WITH tableA AS (
SELECT ["T001", "T002", "T003"] AS T_id, [1, 5] AS L_id
UNION ALL
SELECT ["T008", "T009"] AS T_id, NULL AS L_id
)

SELECT * FROM tableA, UNNEST(L_id) AS unnest
```

When I executed this code, I expected the result such as that below.

```
RowNumber  T-id            L-id  unnest
1          T001,T002,T003  1,5   1
2          T001,T002,T003  1,5   5
3          T004,T005       NULL  NULL
```

But I get this result instead:

```
RowNumber  T-id            L-id  unnest
1          T001,T002,T003  1,5   1
2          T001,T002,T003  1,5   5
```

I lost the third row.
Then, I saw the official Google documentation, which states the following:

```
UNNEST treats NULL as follows.
 ・NULL and empty ARRAY generate zero rows.
 ・An ARRAY containing NULL generates a row containing a NULL value.
```

But I don't want to lose my null row.

How can I keep the null row?

Please tell me the solution...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Instead of CROSS JOIN, use LEFT JOIN. This will return a row with nulls for an empty array. You may also be interested in the [working with arrays topic](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening-arrays) from the documentation.

```
#StandardSQL
WITH tableA AS (
  SELECT ["T001", "T002", "T003"] AS T_id, [1, 5] AS L_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ["T008", "T009"] AS T_id, NULL AS L_id
)
SELECT * FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(L_id) AS value;
```